# How can I disable sub sample request under a parent request which is unnecessary in jmeter?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to disable a sub-sample request embedded in jmeter parent request that follows a redirect of the main request.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 boxes under the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

- `Redirect Automatically` - will still redirect but you won't see sub-results
- `Follow Redirects` - will redirect and you will see the results
- both unticked - no redirects will happen at all, you will have to manage it manually, i.e. check [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header

If you want to amend the behaviour for all the HTTP Request samplers - take a look at [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices) which allows supplying default values for all the HTTP Request samplers in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a sub-sample request by simply unchecking the "Enabled" checkbox located in the sub-sample request. If you don't need the sub-sample request at all, you can simply remove it from the test plan by selecting it and pressing the delete key.

In some cases, you may want to temporarily disable a sub-sample request for debugging purposes. To do this, you can add a "Interruptible Timer" to the sub-sample request. This will pause the execution of the sub-sample request for a specified amount of time. You can then re-enable the sub-sample request by removing the Interruptible Timer.